# How to connect multiple elements together in knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Say I have

```
<div class="cow array">
  <span class"cow-type" data-bind="text: cowType"
  </span>
  <i class="button remove-cow" ></i>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: cowType" />
... more cow types
```

How do I use checkboxes:checkde to add a cow type, a remove-cow button/or checkboxes:unchecked to remove a cow type, and span.cow-type to display cow type text all at once using knockout.js?

Comment: `Subscriptions` (as mentioned below), [with bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html), and [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) all "associate" elements with one another by one means or another. You would need to decide which setup fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll want to subscribe to the cowType observable.  When it changes to true, add your cow type; when it changes to false, remove your cowType

Something like

```
myVm.cowType.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if (newValue){
        //add cow type
    } else {
        //remove cow type
    }
});
```